# How to fast check for http success 200 having range of IP addresses while using HttpClient in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I want to quick check range of IP addresses in local network for http success 200 of given URI using class `HttpClient` in Universal Windows Platform

If success add to list. If failure give up fast go to next in iteration.

Here is sample code I use.

```
private async void ScanLocalNetwork()
{
        string localIpAddress = GetLocalIpAddress();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localIpAddress))
        {
            List<IPAddress> IpAddressList = new List<IPAddress>();
            IpAddressList = GetListOfLocalIpAddresses(localIpAddress);
            ListOfScannedIpAddresses = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach (var ipAddress in IpAddressList)
            {                    
                IsSearchingVisible = true; //show progress ring for list

                var validAddress = await SendHttpRequest(ipAddress.ToString());

                if (validAddress)
                {
                    ListOfScannedIpAddresses.Add(ipAddress.ToString());                        
                }
            }

            IsIpListVisible = true;
            IsSearchingVisible = false;
        }
}

private async Task<bool> SendHttpRequest(string ipAddressToCheck)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage reposneMsg;
        string address = String.Empty;


        address = "http://" + ipAddressToCheck + "/RemoteControl/Volume/get";
        var uri = new Uri(address, UriKind.Absolute);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //IsChecking = true;
            try
            {
                reposneMsg = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                return reposneMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This methods are slow but works. Any idea how speed this up?

Comment: use `Parallel.ForEach` loop, but i suppose you should change `ObservableCollection` to some thread safe collection.

Comment: I have checked Parallel.ForEach but this blocked UI which is I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait for the previous task to finish before calling SendHttpRequest again.

You can add them all to `Task[]` and then [call WhenAll in the end](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall). Something like this:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[IpAddressList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < IpAddressList.Count; i++)
{
    Task task = SendHttpRequest(IpAddressList[i].ToString());
    tasks[i] = task;
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Othen than that, you could set the HttpClient `Timeout` to something shorter to get the request to time out sooner.

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000);
```

EDIT: I updated the code based on the comments!

EDIT 2: You are evaluating task result immediately after you add it to the task array, which defeats the purpose. First start all the tasks, then wait for them to all finish, then go through the list of task results and take the IP addresses that you need.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[IpAddressList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < IpAddressList.Count; i++)
{
    Task<bool> task = SendHttpRequest(IpAddressList[i].ToString());

    tasks[i] = task;
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    if (tasks[i].Result)
    {
        ListOfScannedIpAddresses.Add(IpAddressList[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with asynchronous here, but with slow respond of httpClient until  give up. Or maybe could you elaborate more?

Comment: Well, it should be faster overall if you fired all the calls at once and then waited for all of them to return instead of doing a single call, then wait, then another single call & wait etc. You could also try setting the client.Timeout to get the request to time out sooner...?

Comment: Calling `task.Start` on a hot task will cause an exception. Also, you're blocking using `WaitAll`. You probably want to await on `WhenAll`.

Comment: I tried that tasks iteration but this blocked UI... or I don't know how to use that in a way igrali suggested: http://pastebin.com/Vf0HJjUr

Comment: Regarding client.Timeout it helped by almost half faster with methods I posted originally so I think it is acceptable. But that task iteration now don't give me to rest...

Comment: @hal9k2 I updated the code to use WhenAll to not block and removed the Start() call.

Comment: SendHttpRequest returning bool so it should be Task<bool> task = SendHttpRequest(ip)... so after if true, then add to list. Although UI is blocked forever even with Task.WhenAll(tasks) :(

Comment: From inside DeleagateCommand prop: _scanNetworkCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => { await ScanLocalNetwork(); }); Check latest paste: http://pastebin.com/ufD398Ln

Comment: @hal9k2 you are calling the task.Result at the wrong time - if(task.Result == true), before you actually started all the tasks. This blocks! You need to go through all the tasks after doing the await Task.WhenAll(tasks); and then check the task results. I am updating the answer now to include this code.

Comment: That helped Thank you @igrali !